# C++ templates and overloading operators

Tags: c++, templates, enums

I have run into some strange behavior. I am not sure if this should work or not. Note that I am not trying to make it work, I am rather concerned with theoretical side. I am using Visual C++ 2010. Observe the following code

```
template <class T_>
ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &out, 
        typename SequenceCheckResult<T_>::directiontype const &direction) {

    switch(direction) {
    case SequenceCheckResult<T_>::None:
        out<<"none o";
        break;
    case SequenceCheckResult<T_>::Horizontal:
        out<<"horizontal _";
        break;
    case SequenceCheckResult<T_>::Vertical:
        out<<"vertical |";
        break;
    case SequenceCheckResult<T_>::ForwardDiagonal:
        out<<"forward diagonal \\";
        break;
    case SequenceCheckResult<T_>::BackwardDiagonal:
        out<<"backward diagonal /";
        break;
    }

    return out;
}
```

Obviously the template class SequenceCheckResult contains an enum named directiontype. Now the code above does not get instantiated and integer value of the variable is printed. Even if I provide specialization, it still does not work. If I create the following function, it is used and the textual value is printed. Notice that the following code and int specialization of the above function only differs by `template<>` line and `<int>` following `operator <<`.

```
ostream &operator << (std::ostream &out, 
         SequenceCheckResult<int>::directiontype const &direction) {

    switch(direction) {
    case SequenceCheckResult<int>::None:
        out<<"none o";
        break;
    case SequenceCheckResult<int>::Horizontal:
        out<<"horizontal _";
        break;
    case SequenceCheckResult<int>::Vertical:
        out<<"vertical |";
        break;
    case SequenceCheckResult<int>::ForwardDiagonal:
        out<<"forward diagonal \\";
        break;
    case SequenceCheckResult<int>::BackwardDiagonal:
        out<<"backward diagonal /";
        break;
    }

    return out;
}
```

I wish to know why this happens, possible causes are:

- Compiler bug
- Implementation defines this behavior
- Standards define this behavior
- I am missing something

Thanks in advance

Comment: More code please. Show us how you are calling this.

Comment: @jmucchiello: std::cout<<obj.direction;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your approach does not and cannot work. You cannot deduce a "container based on an element"!

For a simple argument, consider this thought experiment:

```
struct Foo { typedef int type; }
struct Bar { typedef int type; }

template <typename T> void deduce_me(typename T::type n) { }
```

Now if I call `deduce_me(5)`, how are we supposed to deduce either `Foo` or `Bar`?

Comment: Supplying a constant made it obvious, thx. Original call was cout<<obj.direction

Answer (score 1):

`SequenceCheckResult<int>::directiontype` is a better match for `SequenceCheckResult<int>::directiontype` than `int` is (because it's exact), but `int` is a better match than `SequenceCheckResult<_T>::directiontype` (because for a given specialization of `SequenceCheckResult<_T>`, `directiontype` could still be any type, even though we did at least specify that it's a type with `typename`).

Edit: and as KerrekSB points out, even if `directiontype` were somehow known to be `int` for all `_T`, that would leave us with no way to determine which `_T` to use, which causes a problem even though we know it doesn't actually matter which `_T` is used.

To work around this, define the enum outside the template class. Defining it inside implies that it depends on `_T`, when it actually doesn't. It may seem convenient for scoping, but the fact that we're writing this `operator<<` means we can't really fully restrict access anyway. Besides, chances are good that constructors and factory methods would really benefit from outside access to `directiontype`.